# How to position <div> directly below another <div>

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position the blue `<div>` which is 700px x 75px below the yellow (main text area). The yellow area will differ in size depending on each page but the blue area will be a footer for copyright etc.

[image]

Below is the CSS so far.

```
body    
{
font-family: Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
color: #000000;
background: white;
margin: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#header 
{
height: 75px;
width: 900px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
position: relative;
}

#socialmediaicons
{
position: absolute;
height: 35px;
top: 30px;
right: 0;
border: 0;
}

.socialmediaicon
{
padding-left: 5px;
}

#maincontent
{
width: 900px;
height: auto;
background: red;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
position: relative;
}

#mainmenu
{
font-family: Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
}

#gallery
{ 
position: absolute;
left: 200px;
top: 0px;
visibility: hidden; 
border: 0px;
width: 700px;
height: 350px;
background: yellow;
}

#maintextcontainer
{
position: absolute;
background: yellow;
top: 350px;
left: 200px;
width: 700px;
font-family: Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
}

#footer 
{
height: 75px;
width: 700px;
background: blue;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

p.maintexttitle
{
font-family: Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 30px;
}

p.maintext
{
font-family: Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
}
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="header">

<div id="socialmediaicons">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/SCNI/277418002319495"            target="_blank" onmouseover="image1.src=loadImage1.src;"  onmouseout="image1.src=staticImage1.src;">
<img name="image1" src="images/socialmedia/sm1_off.jpg"   class="socialmediaicon" /></a>

<a href="https://twitter.com/scnidesign" target="_blank" onmouseover="image2.src=loadImage2.src;" onmouseout="image2.src=staticImage2.src;">
<img name="image2" src="images/socialmedia/sm2_off.jpg" class="socialmediaicon" /></a>

<a href="http://instagram.com/scnidesign" target="_blank" onmouseover="image3.src=loadImage3.src;" onmouseout="image3.src=staticImage3.src;">
<img name="image3" src="images/socialmedia/sm3_off.jpg" class="socialmediaicon" /></a>

<a href="http://www.smicon4.com" target="_blank" onmouseover="image4.src=loadImage4.src;" onmouseout="image4.src=staticImage4.src;">
<img name="image4" src="images/socialmedia/sm4_off.jpg" class="socialmediaicon" /></a>

<a href="https://dribbble.com/SCNI" target="_blank" onmouseover="image5.src=loadImage5.src;" onmouseout="image5.src=staticImage5.src;">
<img name="image5" src="images/socialmedia/sm5_off.jpg" class="socialmediaicon" /></a>
</div>

</div>



<div id="maincontent">

<div id="mainmenu">
<img src="images/logo.jpg">
<p class="mainmenu"><a href="index.html" class="mainmenu">home</a></p>
<p class="mainmenu"><a href="about.html" class="mainmenu">about</a></p>
<p class="mainmenu"><a href="work.html" class="mainmenu">work</a></p>
<p class="mainmenu"><a href="work.html" class="mainmenu">services</a></p>
<p class="servicesmenu"><a href="design.html" class="servicesmenu">design</a>     </p>
<p class="servicesmenu"><a href="development.html"     class="servicesmenu">development</a></p>
<p class="mainmenu"><a href="contact.html" class="mainmenu">contact</a></p>
</div>

<div id="gallery"></div>

<div id="maintextcontainer">
<p class="maintexttitle"><strong>welcome</strong></p>
<p class="maintext">At SCNI Design, we offer cost effective Logo, Graphic  and Website design and developmental services to small businesses across the   globe.</p>
</div>

<div id="footer"></div>

</div>



</body>

</html>
```

I was able to get the divs aligned on top of eachother but now there is a gap between each. see screenshot. there shouldn't be any red between green, yellow and blue sections.[image: screenshot]

Comment: Post your HTML too please.

Comment: Please edit your post and provide us with the HTML.

Comment: Just a sidenote: When I see something like this, I just have to recommend Bootstrap 3.  Look into it.  It makes this kind of stuff a breeze.

Comment: Just a note, with one div after another in the markup, the natural behavior would be for the divs to stack one above the other - you might have an easier time if you eliminated position:absolute and position:relative from your CSS as much as possible.

Comment: Go research _collapsing/adjoining margins_. Has been discussed a lot of times already.

Answer (score 0):

Your footer CSS should be:

```
.footer{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sticky footer
http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

It solves also your flowing problem

Answer (score 0):

I plopped your code into a jsfiddle but couldn't replicate your results. Just from looking at your CSS as is, I think your solution would be to add position: relative; to the footer.

The position rule takes an element out of normal document flow. In the case of divs, their inherent display: block; will naturally stack themselves on top of one another. By using position: absolute; and position: relative, you are taking the divs out of the document flow and positioning them absolutely (so that top: 0; will hit the top of the window) or relatively (so that top: 0; will hit the bottom of the next highest element).

Using the position rule for layout is very messy and unscalable. The proper way to do this would be to use floats and clears. Your code betrays a lack of proper understanding of CSS, which is OK. If that's the case, I'd encourage you to use Bootstrap instead. It abstracts the minutae and trivia of CSS and will get your layout up and running in much less time. If you're interested in learning more about CSS, I'd recommending reading about blocks, position, floats and clears.